Calling a method returned from another method in Powershell
I'm trying to invoke a function returned from another function. Basically I have a bunch of functions to be called depending on some condition:
function func1 {write-host "hello func1"}
function func2 {write-host "hello func2"}
# ...

function getfunc([char]$condition) {
    switch ($condition) {
        '1' {return func1}
        '2' {return func2}
        # ...
    }
}

function main {
    &getfunc('1')
}

Calling main yields the correct result hello func1. However, I can't seem to make these work for class methods as they require me to specify the type of returned value for a method:
class MyClass {

    [char]$condition

    [void] func1() {write-host "hello func1"}
    [void] func2() {write-host "hello func2"}
    # ...

    [string[]] getfunc() {        # what type to put in here ?
        switch ($this.condition) {
            '1' {return $this.func1}
            '2' {return $this.func2}
            # ...
        }
        return ""
    }

    [void] main() {
        $this.condition = '1'
        & $this.getfunc()
    }
}

[MyClass]::new().main()


I tried using [string[]] with no luck:
& : The term 'void func1()' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

How do I do this ?

As they are methods ("functions") you will need to use parentheses: $this.func1() or in case you want to address them as a calculated properties you need to use class accessors, see Is it possible to override the Getter/Setter functions in a powershell 5 class? and #21079 Implement Class Accessors,.

@iRon Did you mean I should call the methods in the switch block (ie, ...'1' {return $this.func1()}... and just retrieve their result in the main method (ie, $this.getfunc())? It's working! But in case where fun1, func2... need parameters (which are defined/modified somewhere in main), it's impossible to pass those parameters in. So I'm trying to call them (func1, func2...) in main instead.

I am not behind a computer so I can't give you a full answer now but something doesn't add up as the two methods (func1 and funct2) return nothing ([void]) and you trying to return $this.func1()) ingetfunc(). I guess you want to replace [void] funct1... with [string] funct1... and write-host with return.

See Class Methods: "Methods define the actions that a class can perform. Methods can take parameters that specify input data. Methods always define an output type. If a method doesn't return any output, it must have the Void output type. If a method doesn't explicitly define an output type, the method's output type is Void.". Note: "This is fundamentally different from how PowerShell functions handle output, where everything goes to the pipeline.".

@iRon Sorry I think my example code was confusing. I will edit to make it clearer, but to be short, I didn't know what to put in these question marks: [????] getfunc() {... and [string[]] was a failed attempt. Ideally, I wish I could just put [function] getfunc(){... as I want getfunc to return a function/method (which later to be called in main) but apparently that's not possible because powershell doesn't have a "function" datatype.

PowerShell is general a loosely language but classes come from outside and are strict. Meaning the methods ("functions") either return nothing ([Void]) or an explicit type. Saying that, that type might even be even and generic [Object] which includes even a $Null or an "enumerable null".

I quess you actually looking for a static method that might be used by multiple instances, see e.g.https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes#example-3---class-with-static-members

in your case to follow Mathias's answer, you will need to change [string[]] getfunc() to [System.Management.Automation.PSMethod] getfunc() and & $this.getfunc() to $this.getfunc().Invoke()

I only just realized my answer failed to address the actual question about method signatures :) Updated

@iRon now that things have worked out, I just realized that main could be rewritten outside of the class (or rewritten as a static method). Thank you so much for your help.

Dereferencing a class method like in your example yields an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSMethod - you can invoke it via the Invoke() method, but not &, so do:
class MyClass {
    [int] $Condition
    [void] func1() { Write-host "hello func1" }
    [void] func2() { Write-host "hello func2" }

    [System.Management.Automation.PSMethod] GetFunc() {
        $func = switch ($this.Condition) {
            1 { $this.func1 }
            2 { $this.func2 }
        }
        return $func
    }

    static [void] Main([int]$condition) {
        # create instance
        $inst = [MyClass]@{ Condition = $condition }

        # select function
        $func = $inst.GetFunc()

        # invoke selected function
        $func.Invoke()
    }
}

[MyClass]::Main(1)


~~powershell doesn't have a "function" datatype~~ it does have one and it's PSMethod. Thank you for mentioning it and introducing .Invoke(). It helps a lot !!

@AcaNg happy to help, but PSMethod is not a "function datatype" - it's a wrapper type for .NET methods
